# How to add a variable to the form so that it is then added to the database (paypal script)?

Tags: variables, paypal, paypal-ipn

I would like to add a variable to paypal payment form. Then I would like it to be added to the database . The variable is called "membre_id" (user ID) and is found in the $_SESSION['membre_id'].

**Here's the code of form processing :**

```
<?php
require 'lib/init.php';

$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] :        (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '');

if ( !empty($action) ) {

switch ( $action ) {
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'paypal_ipn':

        require ('lib/vendor/ipnlistener.php');
        $listener = new IpnListener();

        try {

            $verified = $listener->processIpn();

            if ( $verified ) {

                // parse our custom field data
                $custom = post('custom');
                if ( $custom ) {
                    parse_str(post('custom'), $data);
                } else {
                    $data = array();
                }
                // pull out some values
                $payment_gross = post('payment_gross');
                $item_name = post('item_name');

                // build customer data
                $name = isset($data['name']) && $data['name'] ? $data['name'] : null;
                $name_arr = explode(' ', trim($name));
                $first_name = $name_arr[0];
                $last_name = trim(str_replace($first_name, '', $name));
                $email = isset($data['email']) && $data['email'] ? $data['email'] : null;
                $description = $item_name ? $item_name : 'no description entered';
                $address = isset($data['address']) && $data['address'] ? $data['address'] : null;
                $city = isset($data['city']) && $data['city'] ? $data['city'] : null;
                $state = isset($data['state']) && $data['state'] ? $data['state'] : null;
                $zip = isset($data['zip']) && $data['zip'] ? $data['zip'] : null;
                $country = isset($data['country']) && $data['country'] ? $data['country'] : null;

                // check for invoice first
                if ( isset($data['invoice_id']) && $data['invoice_id'] ) {
                    $invoice = Model::factory('Invoice')->find_one($data['invoice_id']);
                    $amount = $invoice->amount;
                    $type = 'invoice';
                    $description = $invoice->description;
                // now check for item
                } elseif ( isset($data['item_id']) && $data['item_id'] ) {
                    $item = Model::factory('Item')->find_one($data['item_id']);
                    $amount = $item->price;
                    $type = 'item';
                // check for input amount
                } elseif ( $payment_gross ) {
                    $amount = $payment_gross;
                    $type = 'input';
                // return error if none found
                } else {
                    $amount = 0;
                    $type = '';
                }

                switch ( post('txn_type') ) {
                    case 'web_accept':

                        // save payment record
                        $payment = Model::factory('Payment')->create();
                        $payment->invoice_id = isset($invoice) ? $invoice->id : null;
                        $payment->name = $name;
                        $payment->email = $email;
                        $payment->amount = $amount;
                        $payment->description = isset($item) ? $item->name : $description;
                        $payment->address = $address;
                        $payment->city = $city;
                        $payment->state = $state;
                        $payment->zip = $zip;
                        $payment->country = $country;
                        $payment->type = $type;
                        $payment->paypal_transaction_id = post('txn_id');
                        $payment->save();

                        // update paid invoice
                        if ( isset($invoice) ) {
                            $invoice->status = 'Paid';
                            $invoice->date_paid = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $invoice->save();
                        }

                        // build email values first
                        $values = array(
                            'customer_name' => $payment->name,
                            'customer_email' => $payment->email,
                            'amount' => currency($payment->amount) . '<small>' . currencySuffix() . '</small>',
                            'description_title' => isset($item) ? 'Item' : 'Description',
                            'description' => $payment->description,
                            'payment_method' => 'PayPal',
                            'transaction_id' => $payment->paypal_transaction_id,
                            'url' => url(''),
                        );
                        email($config['email'], 'payment-confirmation-admin', $values, 'You\'ve received a new payment!');
                        email($payment->email, 'payment-confirmation-customer', $values, 'Thank you for your payment to ' . $config['name']);

                    break;

                    case 'subscr_signup':

                        try {

                            $unique_subscription_id = uniqid();
                            // save subscription record
                            $subscription = Model::factory('Subscription')->create();
                            $subscription->unique_id = $unique_subscription_id;
                            $subscription->paypal_subscription_id = post('subscr_id');
                            $subscription->name = $name;
                            $subscription->email = $email;
                            $subscription->address = $address;
                            $subscription->city = $city;
                            $subscription->state = $state;
                            $subscription->zip = $zip;
                            $subscription->country = $country;
                            $subscription->description = isset($item) ? $item->name : $description;
                            $subscription->price = post('amount3');
                            $subscription->billing_day = date('j', strtotime(post('subscr_date')));
                            $subscription->length = $config['subscription_length'];
                            $subscription->interval = $config['subscription_interval'];
                            $subscription->trial_days = $config['enable_trial'] ? $config['trial_days'] : null;
                            $subscription->status = 'Active';
                            $subscription->date_trial_ends = $config['enable_trial'] ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $config['trial_days'] . ' days')) : null;
                            $subscription->save();

                            $trial = $subscription->date_trial_ends ? ' <span style="color:#999999;font-size:16px">(Billing starts after your ' . $config['trial_days'] . ' day free trial ends)</span>' : '';
                            $values = array(
                                'customer_name' => $name,
                                'customer_email' => $email,
                                'amount' => currency(post('amount3')) . '<small>' . currencySuffix() . '</small>' . $trial,
                                'description_title' => isset($item) ? 'Item' : 'Description',
                                'description' => isset($item) ? $item->name : $description,
                                'payment_method' => 'PayPal',
                                'subscription_id' => $subscription->paypal_subscription_id,
                                'manage_url' => url('manage.php?subscription_id=' . $unique_subscription_id)
                            );
                            email($config['email'], 'subscription-confirmation-admin', $values, 'You\'ve received a new recurring payment!');
                            email($email, 'subscription-confirmation-customer', $values, 'Thank you for your recurring payment to ' . $config['name']);

                        } catch (Exception $e) {

                        }

                    break;

                    case 'subscr_cancel':
                        $subscription = Model::factory('Subscription')->where('paypal_subscription_id', post('subscr_id'))->find_one();
                        if ( $subscription ) {
                            $subscription->status = 'Canceled';
                            $subscription->date_canceled = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $subscription->save();
                            // send subscription cancelation email now
                            $values = array(
                                'customer_name' => $subscription->name,
                                'customer_email' => $subscription->email,
                                'amount' => currency($subscription->price) . '<small>' . currencySuffix() . '</small>',
                                'description' => $subscription->description,
                                'payment_method' => 'PayPal',
                                'subscription_id' => $subscription->paypal_subscription_id
                            );
                            email($config['email'], 'subscription-canceled-admin', $values, 'A recurring payment has been canceled.');
                            email($subscription->email, 'subscription-canceled-customer', $values, 'Your recurring payment to ' . $config['name'] . ' has been canceled.');
                        }
                    break;

                    case 'subscr_eot':
                        $subscription = Model::factory('Subscription')->where('paypal_subscription_id', post('subscr_id'))->find_one();
                        if ( $subscription && $subscription->status == 'Active' ) {
                            $subscription->status = 'Expired';
                            $subscription->date_canceled = null;
                            $subscription->save();
                        }
                    break;

                }



            } else {
                die();
            }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die();
        }

    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'paypal_success':
        go('index.php#status=paypal_success');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'paypal_subscription_success':
        go('index.php#status=paypal_subscription_success');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'paypal_cancel':
        msg('You canceled your PayPal payment, no payment has been made.', 'warning');
        go('index.php');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'delete_payment':
        if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {
            $payment = Model::factory('Payment')->find_one($_GET['id']);
            $payment->delete();
        }
        msg('Payment has been deleted successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=payments');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'delete_subscription':
        if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {
            $subscription = Model::factory('Subscription')->find_one($_GET['id']);
            $subscription->delete();
        }
        msg('Subscription has been deleted successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=subscriptions');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'create_invoice':
        if ( post('email') && post('amount') && post('description') ) {
            $unique_invoice_id = uniqid();
            $invoice = Model::factory('Invoice')->create();
            $invoice->unique_id = $unique_invoice_id;
            $invoice->email = post('email');
            $invoice->description = post('description');
            $invoice->amount = post('amount');
            $invoice->number = post('number');
            $invoice->status = 'Unpaid';
            $invoice->date_due = post('date_due') ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(post('date_due'))) : null;
            $invoice->save();
        }
        $number = $invoice->number ? $invoice->number : $invoice->id();
        if ( post('send_email') && post('send_email') ) {
            $values = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'amount' => currency($invoice->amount) . '<small>' . currencySuffix() . '</small>',
                'description' => $invoice->description,
                'date_due' => !is_null($invoice->date_due) ? date('F jS, Y', strtotime($invoice->date_due)) : '<em>no due date set</em>',
                'url' => url('?invoice_id=' . $unique_invoice_id)
            );
            email($invoice->email, 'invoice', $values, 'Invoice from ' . $config['name']);
            $msg = ' and sent';
        }
        msg('Invoice has been created' . (isset($msg) ? $msg : '') . ' successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=invoices');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'delete_invoice':
        if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {
            $invoice = Model::factory('Invoice')->find_one($_GET['id']);
            $invoice->delete();
        }
        msg('Invoice has been deleted successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=invoices');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'add_item':
        if ( post('name') && post('price') ) {
            $item = Model::factory('Item')->create();
            $item->name = post('name');
            $item->price = post('price');
            $item->save();
        }
        msg('Item has been added successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=items');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'edit_item':
        if ( post('id') && post('name') && post('price') ) {
            $item = Model::factory('Item')->find_one(post('id'));
            $item->name = post('name');
            $item->price = post('price');
            $item->save();
        }
        msg('Item has been edited successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=items');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'delete_item':
        if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {
            $item = Model::factory('Item')->find_one($_GET['id']);
            $item->delete();
        }
        msg('Item has been deleted successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=items');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'save_config':
        if ( post('config') && is_array(post('config')) ) {
            foreach ( post('config') as $key => $value ) {
                $config = Model::factory('Config')->where('key', $key)->find_one();
                if ( $config ) {
                    $config->value = $value;
                    $config->save();
                }
            }
        }
        msg('Your settings have been saved successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php#tab=settings');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'login':
        if ( 
            post('admin_username') && post('admin_username') == $config['admin_username'] && 
            post('admin_password') && post('admin_password') == $config['admin_password']
        ) {
            // login successful, set session
            $_SESSION['admin_username'] = $config['admin_username'];
        } else {
            // login failed, set error message
            msg('Login attempt failed, please try again.', 'danger');
        }
        go('admin.php');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'logout':
        unset($_SESSION['admin_username']);
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        msg('You have been logged out successfully.', 'success');
        go('admin.php');
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    case 'install':
        $status = true;
        $message = '';
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db_host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db_name'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password']);
            $sql = file_get_contents('lib/sql/install.sql');
            $result = $db->exec($sql);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $status = false;
            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }
        $response = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message
        );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        die(json_encode($response));
    break;
```

/***********************************************************************************************************************/

```
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter in the API request called "custom".  That's what you need to pass your data in and then it will come back within IPN as $_POST['custom']